# Drupal error: trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I made a small website for a local sport team and everything worked and went fine. The host went down for a short while (payment issues) and after the site went back up there were these errors on some of the pages:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in block_block_view()
>   (line 245 of
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/brewerslacrosse.be/httpdocs/modules/block/block.module).
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in block_block_view()
>   (line 245 of
>   /home/httpd/vhosts/brewerslacrosse.be/httpdocs/modules/block/block.module).

I assume it has something to do with the modules but I'm not sure. Any help would be appreciated.

error can be seen of the website atm: [site](http://www.buggenhoutlacrosse.be)

Comment: These are `notices` not `errors` you can turn them off

Comment: lol thx, already fixed. Any idea what that notice stands for though?